# parent elements styling should not apply to child element

Tags: html, css, less

**html**

```
<div class="span2 style-for-header">MWCU234566 <a href="#">Edit</a></div>
```

and **css**

```
 .style-for-header{
    font-family: 'Tahoma,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

now i want exclude anchor tag from applying this styling. is there any way ?

Comment: you can use this css `div.style-for-header a{text-decoration:line-through;color:red;}`

Comment: Create a style for the anchor that sets it to override the parent class.

Comment: Apply a different font to the anchor tag. Child elements inherit the font properties of their parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can CSS specificity CSS rule here. If you don't want the css apply for `anchor`tag.

```
.style-for-header{
    font-family: 'Tahoma,sans-serif';
    font-size: 19px;
    color:green;
  }

div.style-for-header a{
    text-decoration:line-through;
    color:red;
    font-size:14px;
}
```

by using above CSS `a` tag will have different style.

Check the ***[Demo.](http://jsbin.com/tutevoja/1/)***